# Why does my Request fail from Angular to Kotlin Spring Boot Backend (but in Postman it works)?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

My call from Angular:

```
const data = {test: "test"}

        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json,, 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem(environment.STORAGE_KEYS.TOKEN) }')
        };

        this.http.post("http://localhost:1234/test", data, httpOptions)
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log("sucesss");
      console.log(response);
    },
    error => {
      console.log("error");
      console.error(error);
    }
  );
```

In my spring boot app:
Controller:

```
@RestController
class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(
        method = [RequestMethod.POST],
        value = ["/test"],
        produces = ["application/json"],
        consumes = ["application/json"]
    )
    fun test(){
        println("test")
    }
}
```

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfig(private val issuersOAuth2Properties: IssuersOAuth2Properties) {

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain? {
        http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll().and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().oauth2ResourceServer{oauth2 ->
            oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(jwtIssuerAuthManager())
        }.authorizeRequests()
        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwtIssuerAuthManager(): AuthenticationManagerResolver<HttpServletRequest?>?{
        return JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver(IssuerManager(issuersOAuth2Properties.issuers))
    }
}
```

CorsConfig:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
class CorsConfig: WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
        logger().info("this is cors here")
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("*").allowedHeaders("*")
    }
}
```

If I dont have a token, It will give 401. That's why i assume my token works.

Network request copied from chrome dev console:

```
curl 'http://localhost:1234/test' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8100/' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciO.....Q3Oz_xw' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-raw '{"test":"test"}' \
  --compressed
```

Stacktrace:

```
scheduleTask @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:11755
_ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8281
onScheduleTask @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8174
_ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8276
Zone.scheduleTask @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8091
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8120
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8685
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:11800
proto.<computed> @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:9042
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:44103
_trySubscribe @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:26437
subscribe @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:26419
innerSubscribe @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:27435
_innerSub @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:28800
_tryNext @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:28793
_next @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:28774
next @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:26906
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:30308
_trySubscribe @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:26437
subscribe @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:26419
call @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:28757
subscribe @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:26417
call @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:28466
subscribe @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:26417
call @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:28628
subscribe @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:26417
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8100/src_app_business-owner_business_add-business_add-business_module_ts.js:158
asyncGeneratorStep @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:129742
_next @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:129764
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:129771
ZoneAwarePromise @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:9436
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:129760
addBusiness @ http://localhost:8100/src_app_business-owner_business_add-business_add-business_module_ts.js:211
AddBusinessPage_form_6_Template_ion_button_click_29_listener @ ng:///AddBusinessPage.js:96
executeListenerWithErrorHandling @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:91120
wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:91158
(anonymous) @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:118042
_ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8293
onInvokeTask @ http://localhost:8100/vendor.js:103217
_ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8293
Zone.runTask @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8043
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:8388
invokeTask @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:9906
globalCallback @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:9943
globalZoneAwareCallback @ http://localhost:8100/polyfills.js:9982
```

Response:
empty

How it looks in the dev console
Written is: cancled, and xhr as type
[image]

I don't see any cors errors in the console.

Comment: Not sure if it is the whole problem but you are sending data to an endpoint that doesn't receive data (no params) so it might fail to map correctly

Comment: The data will just be ignored, with postman the reqeust works, and the curl wich i can copy from chrome console works too

Comment: What is the http client in Angular?

Comment: @grekier because my frontend uses angular

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the page is reloaded before the request was done. I had a typo in the type of the button in html => default is submit. That means the page is reloaded and the request can't be finished.